# Error When JavaScript Code Told to Log Mouse Pointer Coordinates

Tags: javascript, events, coordinates

In my JavaScript code, I need to get the coordinates of the mouse pointer with the `event` variable, using `setInterval()` to supplement it and update the coordinates. Instead of logging the coordinates, it gives me an error. Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(event.pageX);
}, 1)
```

The error states that it doesn't know what the `event` variable is. I've seen answers that said use `addEventListener`, but I don't see how that could work with the `setInterval()` function.

Comment: _"but I don't see how that could work with the setInterval() function"_ - me neither. You _should_ subscribe to the `mousemove` event, and then update the current position from within the callback function of that. Intervals or timeouts don't come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using an event listener, rather than `setInterval`, as opposed to needing to use both.

You can do the following:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    console.log('event: ', event)
});
```

This will track your mouse position whenever it is moved.